# Trouble migrating from MySQL to Derby: Invalid cursor state - no current row

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, derby

My program was working fine while connected to a MySQL database, but now that I have it connected to an embedded Derby file database, it is no longer inserting new rows.

Whenever I try to insert a new row, I get the error:

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row.

The stack trace is referring to a certain line in my getValueAt() function in my table model:

```
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
    {
        Object object = null;

        try 
        {
            resultSet.absolute(row + 1);

            object = resultSet.getObject(column + 1);  // <---------

            return object;
        } 
        catch (SQLException se) 
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return "";
    }
```

But I'm pretty sure that that is resulting in an error because no row is getting inserted in the first place.

Here is my addRow() method in my table model:

```
    public void addRow(Object[] newRow)
    {       
        try
        {
            resultSet.moveToInsertRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < newRow.length; i++)
            {
                resultSet.updateObject(i + 2, newRow[i]);
            }

            resultSet.insertRow(); 

            rowCount++;

            fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount - 1, rowCount - 1);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

(The i+2 in resultSet.updateObject(i + 2, newRow[i]); is just to skip the first primary key column.)

I also have auto commit set to false so I can implement a simple Save button by calling connection.commit().

My statement object has the following flags set:

statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

As I said, the code was working fine with MySQL.

Does anyone know why it is having trouble inserting a new row?

Comment: Solution: At the end of the addRow() method, after I call resultSet.insertRow(), I refresh the resultSet by populating it with the results of a new database query.  This was the only way I could think of to make sure the result set is up-to-date with the newly added row.  So when the JTable starts calling getValueAt() immediately after, it will see the new row in the result set.  But I'm still not sure why this is necessary in Derby, but not in MySQL.

Comment: You need to call `rs.moveToCurrentRow();` after inserting; that might be the reason (not sure though)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I still get the same error even when doing rs.moveToCurrentRow().  The only thing that has worked so far is to explicitly update the resultset by running a new query where I select all the data from the table.  It *seems* like resultSet.insertRow() is not updating the result set, but is updating the underlying database.  This seems odd because I have connection.setAutoCommit(false).